# Proof that $ \frac{3\pi}{8}< \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos{\sin{x}} dx < \frac{49\pi}{128}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, inequality, proof-writing

Proof that
$$
\frac{3\pi}{8} <
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x <
\frac{49\pi}{128}
$$

Can somebody give me some instruction how to deal with inequality like that? My current idea is:

I see $\frac{3\pi}{8}$ on the left. So I think that I can prove that
$$ \frac{3}{4}<\cos{\sin{x}} $$
And after take integral:
$$ \frac{3x}{4} \rightarrow \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{3\pi}{8} $$
But it is not true because
$$ \cos{\sin{x}} \geqslant \cos{1} \approx 0.5403 < 3/4$$
What have I do in such situation?

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos{\left(\sin{x}\right)}~dx=\frac{\pi J_0\left(1\right)}{2}$

Comment: what is $J_0$ symbol?

Comment: @Tester1998 $J_0$ is a Bessel function

Comment: I didn't have that on my lecture

Comment: Numerically that is $1.178097245096172 < 1.201969715317207 < 1.202640937702343$, so the bounds are pretty sharp.

Comment: @MartinR especially I don't have idea to the right part, but I am really surprised that this method doesn't work for the left side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint for one part**, using [this inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700608/use-of-inequality-1-cos-x-leq-x2-2) and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities) 
$$\cos{x} \geq 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$$
we [have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20(1-(sin(x))%5E2%2F2)%20dx,%20x%20from%200%20to%20pi%2F2)
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos{\sin{x}} dx > \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(1-\frac{\sin^2{x}}{2}\right)dx=\frac{3 \pi}{8}$$

Comment: And $\cos{x} \leq 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} +  \frac{x^4}{4!}$ gives the upper bound.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you, @MartinR!

Comment: So Taylor do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Follow-up to @rtybase:

$$
\cos x\le 1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}\implies
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\sin xdx<\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(1-\frac{\sin^2 x}2+\frac{\sin^4 x}{24}\right)dx=\frac{49\pi}{128}.
$$

Comment: #Maclaurin ${}{}{}$