# Discontinuity of the function $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\cos^n (1/n^x)$.

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\cos^n (\frac{1}{n^x})$. If $|\cos(1/n^x)|<1$, then  $f(x)=0$. We want to find a number $x$ such that $\cos (1/n^x)=\pm 1$, so that $f(x)=\pm 1$. At such $x$, $f$ would be discontinuous. How to locate such point in $(0,\infty).$ We may find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ which is convergent in $(0,\infty)$ and for which $\lim_{n\rightarrow}\cos ^n(1/n^{x_n})=1.$

Comment: Given the question history, I could not find any improvement in the quality of your questions. Please improve the question by providing your own ideas and/or contexts. Also, check [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: It seems to find $x$ such that $1/n^x=m\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You can get some insights from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254573/nature-of-sum-left-cos-frac1n-alpha-rightn/3254683#3254683).

Comment: Using the fact that $\log\cos(t)\sim-t^2/$ as $t\to 0$, meaning that the ratio of two functions converges to $1$ as $t\to0$, we get $$\log\left(\cos^n(n^{-x})\right)\sim n \cdot \left(-\frac{n^{-2x}}{2}\right)=-\frac{n^{1-2x}}{2}.$$ Using this, you can easily conclude that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x<\frac{1}{2}\\e^{-1/2},&x=\frac{1}{2}\\1,&x>\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$